# PHP $_GET request inside class construct, not working

Tags: php, get, construct

This code doesn't work.  The $_GET variables are set, but this code always returns $model, $manufacturer, etc, as being empty.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php    
class Tiles extends Phones {
    private $model;
    private $manufacturer;
    private $all;

    function __construct() {
        $this->model = $_GET['model'] ?? null;
        $this->manufacturer = $_GET['manufacturer'] ?? null;
        $this->all = $_GET;
    }

    function showEntry() {
        echo $model;
    }
}
?>
```

This is my first time using the `__construct` method, so if i'm missing something obvious, please, point me in the right direction.

Edit: I should add, if I simply use $_GET['model'], etc in my showEntry() method, it works.

Comment: use `echo $this->model`

Comment: I wanna cry when I see this constructor with `$_GET`....2017

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `echo $this->model;` instead of just `echo $model;` inside of `showEntry()`.

Comment: what's the easiest way to set it so I can simply call $model, etc?

Comment: That's not how Object Oriented Programming in PHP works. `$model` is declared as private for the `Tiles` class. When inside a class, variables are called by `$this->`, if you don't use `$this->` you are only referring to `$model` inside of the `showEntry()` scope.